# Copy and paste picture from excel to word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to try another method that is not to export the images from excel and then import them to word.
This method makes use of copy and paste, however I have encountered a problem using different versions of Office. In some it pastes it as InlineShape and in another as Shape.

I don't know how to correctly reference a variable in the pasted image. I thought I could use something like `set object = selection` after pasting the image but it doesn't work.

The purpose of referencing it is to add a text that allows me to delete it if I insert an update of the same image.

For the inlineshape I have solved it using the InlineShape.Range.BookmarkID property but if it is a Shape object I don't know the way.

Could anyone help me?

**Code:**

```vb
Sub Copy_Paste_Image_Bookmark(sBookmark As String, sImage As String, Optional sSheet As String, Optional sWorkbook As String)

   
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, xlWrk As Excel.Workbook, xlSht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oShp As Excel.Shape
    
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    
    Set xlWrk = xlApp.Workbooks(sWorkbook)
    
    Set xlSht = xlWrk.Worksheets(sSheet)
    
    xlSht.Shapes(sImage).Copy
    
    'Control for word
    Dim docWord As Word.Document
    Dim oBookmark As Bookmark, rBookmark As Word.Range, oInLiShp As Word.InlineShape
    Dim lInLiShapes As Long, idx As Long, lInLiShapes_old As Long
    Dim lShapes As Long, lShapes_old As Long, bIsInlineShape As Boolean, bIsShape As Boolean
    Dim oShape As Word.Shape, oShapes As Word.Shapes
    
    Set docWord = ThisDocument
    
    'If exists bookmark
    If docWord.Bookmarks.Exists(sBookmark) Then
        Set oBookmark = docWord.Bookmarks(sBookmark)
        
        Set rBookmark = oBookmark.Range
    
        'Delete previous text
        'rBookmark.MoveEndUntil Chr(46), wdForward   'chr(12) jump page
        rBookmark.Expand Unit:=wdParagraph
        rBookmark.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1

        If StrComp(rBookmark.Text, "Text test") = 0 Then rBookmark.Delete
    
        'Delete previous image
        idx = GetIndex_Inlishape_BookmarkID(oBookmark.Range.BookmarkID)
        If idx > 0 Then docWord.InlineShapes(idx).Delete
        
        'Recover count of shapes
        lInLiShapes_old = docWord.InlineShapes.Count
        lShapes_old = docWord.Shapes.Count
        
        'Paste image
        rBookmark.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
        
        'Recover new count shapes
        lInLiShapes = docWord.InlineShapes.Count
        lShapes = docWord.Shapes.Count
        
        'Determine type pasted shape
        bIsInlineShape = lInLiShapes > lInLiShapes_old
        bIsShape = lShapes > lShapes_old
        
        'If is inlineshape
        If bIsInlineShape And bIsShape = False Then
            idx = GetIndex_Inlishape_BookmarkID(oBookmark.Range.BookmarkID)
            Set oInLiShp = docWord.InlineShapes(idx)
        ElseIf bIsShape And bIsInlineShape = False Then
            Set oShape = docWord.Shapes(lShapes)
            
            'Convert to inlineshape
            Set oInLiShp = oShape.ConvertToInlineShape
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Change some options
        oInLiShp.Title = sImage
        oInLiShp.Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    Else
        MsgBox "The bookmark " & sBookmark & " doesn't exist in the document.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Not exists bookmark"
    End If
End Sub

Function GetIndex_Inlishape_BookmarkID(bkm_ID As Long) As Long
    Dim o As InlineShape, i As Long
    
    For Each o In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
        i = i + 1
        If o.Range.BookmarkID = bkm_ID Then
            Select Case o.Type
                Case wdInlineShapePicture
                    GetIndex_Inlishape_BookmarkID = i
                    Exit Function
                End Select
        End If
    Next
    
    GetIndex_Inlishape_BookmarkID = 0
End Function
```

Comment: You can use [ConvertToInlineShape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shaperange.converttoinlineshape) method to convert `Shape` to `InlineShape`, it also returns an `InlineShape` object so you can do `Set inlineShp = Shp.ConvertToInlineShape` and then do whatever you want later. What I typically do is to ensure everything stays as InlineShapes so when I paste an image, I will check if theres any ShapeRange and convert if there is.

Comment: It would probably be better to use the `AlternativeText` property to store any version info you need to compare. Both `InlineShape` and `Shape` have this property.

Comment: @RaymondWu When pasting the image I have no way to reference it from the Shapes collection, that is the problem.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Yes that's the idea but I need to reference the pasted image (shape or inlineshape) before to do that.

Comment: @Ovichan Your code have somewhat tried to check for its type after pasting and then convert to `InlineShape` so technically you would have 0 shape before pasting. So after pasting, `If docWord.Shapes.Count <> 0 Then Set inlineShpVar = docWord.Shapes(1).ConvertToInlineShape`

Comment: @Ovichan Not related to your problem but `docWord` is quite redundant as you can already reference `ThisDocument` in your code.

Comment: @RaymondWu The problem I am asking for is to assign the inserted shape by pasting. I knew that if the collection is empty and I add a shape the way to reference it would be as you have put it but that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with Set oShape = docWord.Shapes(sImage) because image pasted keep the name of shape from Excel although with .count of the collection Shapes run fine.

However with .count of the collection inlineshapes not run fine because Word orders the elements, first the shapepictures and after shapecharts.

Thanks.